Prove that at least two students will end up with fewer roommates after the reassignment
Problem: In a dormitory, there are $n$ rooms, and $m$ students $(m > n)$ currently living in their assigned rooms. When a new room is added, the students are reassigned into the $n+1$ rooms such that no room remains empty.
Prove that at least two students will end up with fewer roommates after the reassignment, regardless of the initial assignment or how the reassignment is done.
Prove the statement in the following cases:

$m = n + 1$ students.
$m > n$ students.

My attempt: For the the first case, it was easy to see that there is exactly one room has two students. After adding a new room, we have to separate them to make sure there is no empty room. They end up with fewer roommates.
My question. Do you have any ways to solve the general case? I have an observation that the total number of roommates before adding the new room $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -1)$ greater than the total number of roommates $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} (y_j-1)$ one student.

@RobinSparrow It's more complicated than that, for two reasons. First, you might have rooms with 3 or fewer residents. Second, the reassignment might also move some people in together.

This is a "well-known" problem (so likely a version exists on MSE, but it's hard to find with different skins, so I'm not posting a solution unless you've done much more work) esp when it just asks for 1 student. Can you prove the version? Let me know if you want a hint for this (you have a good idea, but note that the expression isn't easy to "understand")$\quad$ Once that is done, use that proof to show that 2 students exist (the sum of some $r_i < 1$ is an integer, so we need at least 2 $r_i$).

@CalvinLin I believe it is more complicated somehow. Because the problem you mentioned care about the box (room) not about the relation between students.

Are you sure they are different? If so, can you elaborate how yours is more complicated? The reskinning translation is student = object and room = box. $\quad$ There I showed that "Prove that there are two objects (students) each of which has the property that it is in a new box (room)  that contains strictly fewer objects (sounders) than the old box (room) that contained it." which is the same as your version "Prove that at least two students(objects) will end up with fewer roommates (objects) after the reassignment, regardless of the initial assignment or how the reassignment is done."

@CalvinLin Ahhh, it was my bad. You are correct ^^
